# Labels missing after conversion from *.mxd to *.kml?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, labeling, google-earth, mxd

I've been trying to convert a map from .mxd to .kml for google earth. The map has municipalities labeled as well as train stations. When I save it and open it in Google Earth, only the train station labels appear.

I have tried moving the municipal layer up in the table of contents before saving. I have also tried taking out the rail stations labels and only having the municipal labels. Neither has done the trick.

Comment: your need to convert your polygons to points [centroid] in order to export labels for Google Earth - Google Earth does not label polygons only points.

Answer (score 4):

Google Earth requires labelled polygons in ArcGIS to be labelled points.

[image]

*use the 'INSIDE' to force points inside the original polygon.

Use Feature to Point (Data Management) Toolbox
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000

add the point layer into your .mxd
label it.

Export to KML/KMZ

Comment: Thanks :) You just saved me many frustrating minutes/hours. Map looks great (and labeled) now.

Comment: Great answer!  If you have multipart data as shown in the graphics above, you may want to consider using the **[Multipart To Singlepart](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003r000000)** tool so that each feature is labeled independently.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, no matter what I do I have all sorts of rendering issues when converting annotations to KMZ. (it could be because I am trying to precisely place 100s of labels in a KMZ) To overcome these problems I convert annotations to polygons which is not an elegant solution but it does work flawlessly every time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The underlying point to understand is that kml is a very different model than that of an ArcGIS (.mxd) map, and in general is more restrictive. As already noted by @mapperz, you can't label a polygon. But there are many other things you also can't do in kml which you'll discover along the way. If you're going to be generating a lot of kml from mxd files (or other sources), it would pay to look over the [kml reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) to understand the range of what can and can't be done.