# UK region overlay on map

Tags: kml, overlay, google-fusion-tables, united-kingdom, region

I'm hoping to overlay UK regions (East Midlands, Wales, London etc) on a Google Map. Ideally the regions could be coloured, opaque and have some form of label. There is no hover / interaction requirements for the overlays.

Q - #1 - It seems like this could be achieved with KML or fusion tables. Which do you think would be better?

Q - #2 - Do you know of a good source for the outline points of these regions? I've got access to points on other maps (SVG - see link below) but not sure if this translates. If regions are not available counties could be used and coloured the same (Counties - see link below )

SVG - http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/datablog/interactive/2012/jul/11/olympians-map-uk-olympics
Counties - http://www.guardian.co.uk/news/datablog/interactive/2011/nov/16/youth-unemployment-map

Many thanks

Comment: you can download a shapefile of the regions from http://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/handle/10672/50

Comment: You can store KML in Fusion tables - http://kh-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/talks/hackhackers/workshop.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Map to KML](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000004p000000) in ArcMap 10.  Labeling the features is not straightforward--although, there is a good discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27311/8104).

1. Begin by creating the map overlay you would like in ArcMap,
   including colored outlines, opacity, etc.
2. Run [Feature to Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000)
3. Turn on the labels in your new point layer
4. Save the map as a .mxd
5. Run [Map to KML](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000004p000000) (Define the output image properties to the
   resolution of your choice)

Regarding data sources, I would recommend checking out this site from [gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/country).  The attached Google Earth image uses this data source and the described methods.

[image]